# On comma separated expressions in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I recently came across [this blog post](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.de/2010/09/dealloc.html) where two flavors of instance variable deallocation are discussed. To give you a summary:

The first approach

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [instanceVar release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

is considered to leave a pointer alive until the method returns. This can lead to undefined behavior.
The second approach

```
- (void)dealloc {
  [instanceVar release], instanceVar = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

is considered to be more stable for production code because the *instaceVar* is set to nil.

OK. Here is the question you've been waiting for:
Are both solutions the same? Or does the comma separation of expressions make them atomic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comma doesn't make it atomic, but there should only be one thread invoking `dealloc` anyway or else you have much, much larger problems on your hands. Setting `instanceVar` to `nil` is unnecessary, it isn't safer, because if there is a bug in your program that somehow uses the dangling value in `instanceVar` it will only manifest differently depending on whether it is `nil` or something else, either way, there is a bug, because *nothing* should be relying on that value.

With ARC this is even less of an issue. A `dealloc` method in ARC is only used to release non-ARC-controlled resources, everything else is automatically handled for you.

Comment: Yeah. That's what the mentioned blog post already said. Could you (in theory) get a situation where you use the _dangling_ value before instanceVar is set to nil?

Comment: @lupz: You *could*, in theory you could have two threads, one of which has overreleased the object and invoked `dealloc` on one thread while `instanceVar` is still being used on the other thread. Note though that this can only manifest as the result of the bug of one thread overreleasing. Setting `instanceVar` to `nil` only changes the behaviour of the bug, it doesn't really solve anything.

Answer (score 2):

The blog post you link to is from 2010.

The more interesting point nowadays is that you have to do neither. If you use ARC, then you can't send a release message to objects.

The setting of `nil` after release was to prevent non-retained objects to be sent messages after they were deallocated and cause a crash. I say non-retained objects, because if they were retained objects, they wouldn't (shouldn't) be released unknowingly. Again, with ARC (as long as you aren't using ARC-lite) you can mark non-retained objects as `weak`, and weak pointers auto-zero; i.e. when the object they point to is deallocated, the pointer is set to nil.

So the second case, with pointers being set to `nil` after a dealloc, is considered safer at run-time, but you don't have to worry about it now, as ARC handles that for you.

Comment: I don't necessarily think it is safer. If something is relying on memory it shouldn't be, you only change the behaviour of this bug by changing it to `nil`. You have a bug either way. While messages to no-op are safe, providing that object to methods that aren't expecting `nil` will still cause unwanted results, (e.g. `rangeOfString:` throws an exception if the argument is `nil`).

Comment: That is the point of it - it's safer at run time, but if you let the exception be thrown then a bug (if there is one) is found during development. But with ARC, there is no longer that debate.

Comment: @Abizem: What I mean is, it's not *safer* in the sense that setting pointers to `nil` is only done out of the hope that *if* something were to rely on a dangling pointer that "the damage" won't be as bad, but in reality, you should ensure *nothing* will use a dangling pointer, i.e. if your program is using a deallocated object your program has a bug. All you're doing by setting the pointer to nil is changing the way the bug manifests, and if you only set it to nil in release builds then you are only ensuring that the bug behaves differently between release and debug builds.

Comment: I agree with you. You shouldn't be sending messages to potentially dangling pointers. I think my point (excuse the pun) is getting lost; what I'm trying to say is with ARC, there is no "debate".